# Replacing process arguments for a C# application

Tags: c#, .net, arguments

Is there a way to replace the values of the arguments of a managed process like it can be done for a native program as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx#9928592)?

Here's a program I wrote trying to do the same thing but it didn't work like the other case:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null) 
            { 
                return; 
            }

            foreach (String arg in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Before: " + arg); 

                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (char* ptr = arg)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < arg.Length; i++)
                        {
                            *(ptr + i) = 'x';
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine("After: " + arg); 
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(): ");

            foreach (String arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
            }
        }
```

And the result is:

```
Before: asdf
After: xxxx
Before: lkjasdf
After: xxxxxxx
Before: ;lkajsdf
After: xxxxxxxx
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs():
ConsoleApplication2.exe
asdf
lkjasdf
;lkajsdf
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are u trying to achieve? cant get u?

Comment: I'd be really, really hesitant to do that.  You're mutating what should be an immutable string, and you don't know if you only had a copy passed into you in the first place.  Perhaps if we knew why this was desirable?

Comment: I'm seeing whether, when sensitive information is passed on the command-line arguments, there is a way to hide them from being viewed by others by Process Explorer or any other tools that can view the command line arguments of a process.

Comment: @Duat: you could spawn a detached child process, pass in the parameters via a named pipe, and let the parent process exit.

Comment: @Duat: you can use the approach given in the [`AnonymousPipeServerStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeserverstream.aspx) documentation to write the arguments to the client (perhaps using a BinaryWriter). If you aren't able to try that approach, let me know.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Thanks for the comments. I've actually been trying those. There are lots of ways to handle this, apparently :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` likely makes use of the native [`GetCommandLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows. However, the return value will be marshaled into .Net strings and will have no effect on the native pointer actually returned by `GetCommandLine()`.

You should assume this is *read-only* and that you have no guarantees writing to the pointer won't cause a fault. I'm sure you could use a P/Invoke definition of `GetCommandLine()` and an `IntPtr` to overwrite the command line, but this is undefined behavior and isn't guaranteed to work in the future (these sort of assumptions are what Raymond often points out in his articles).